# Hover in vue app on certain element in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

```html
<v-toolbar-items>
  <v-btn 
    color="primary"
    active-class="default-class"
    flat
    v-for="item in horizontalNavItems"
    :key="item.title"
    :to="item.link">{{item.title}}</v-btn>
</v-toolbar-items>
```

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    };
  },
  computed: {
    horizontalNavItems () {
      return [
        { title: "About Us", link: "/" },
        { title: "The Brand", link: "/" },
        { title: "Investors", link: "/"},
        { title: "People", link: "/" },
        { title: "Contact Us", link: "/" }
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

I need help with my VUE app, @mouseover and @mouseleave on a certain element in this navigation v-for loop when I hover let's say, Investors, I want a dropdown, as shown on the picture?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use [Vuetify Hover](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/hover)

Answer (score 0):

Read this:
https://michaelnthiessen.com/hover-in-vue/
but basically you need to create a `mouseover` event and then respond to it either with a variable or with a function to display your list. The list can be `v-if="someVal"` (meaning if `someVal` is true)

Answer (score 0):

when the mouse is hovering over the element. This can be figured out by keeping track of when the mouse enters the element, and when the mouse leaves the element.

```
<v-toolbar-items>
      <v-btn 
        color="primary"
        active-class="default-class"
        flat
        v-for="item in horizontalNavItems"
        :key="item.title"
        :to="item.link"
        @mouseover="somefuntion
        @mouseleave="somefuntion"{{item.title}}</v-btn>
    </v-toolbar-items>
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/intotheprogram/pen/ZjxZdg